# MySQL - Arithmetic operations with two relations

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get the total amount of money paid by each customer minus the amount collected (`em_paid_to`)?

table customer

```
cust_id INT
f_name VARCHAR
l_name VARCHAR
email VARCHAR
c_limit INT
```

table transaction

```
id INT
em_paid_by VARCHAR
em_paid_to VARCHAR
amount INT
trans_date DATE
```

I already tried this to get the total paid by each customer but it did not work:

```
SELECT C.F_NAME, C.L_NAME, COUNT(T.EM_PAID_BY), SUM(T.AMOUNT)
FROM CUSTOMER C 
JOIN TRANSACTION T ON C.EMAIL = T.EM_PAID_BY;
```

...and this to get the total collected by each customer, still the same error and I need to get the difference between the two results.

```
SELECT C.F_NAME, C.L_NAME, COUNT(T.EM_PAID_TO), SUM(T.AMOUNT)
FROM CUSTOMER C 
JOIN TRANSACTION T ON C.EMAIL = T.EM_PAID_TO;
```

What I am hoping to get is like this **Old McDonald oldmcdonald@gmail.com 2000**
i.e *(2000 + 4000 + 1000) - (2000 + 3000) = 2000*

Comment: In what way did your queries not work? Wrong result? Error message? Help us to help you...

Comment: You need to test whether t_amount should be negated in the sum. (Hint CASE) and search for conditional aggregation.

Comment: This is the error I get. ERROR: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'C.f_name'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by.

Comment: ...and when I add group by parameter, it gives this. ERROR: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'C.l_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing queries generate errors because they use aggregate functions (`SUM()`, `COUNT()`) without a `GROUP BY` clause to list all non-aggregated columns.

To solve your requirement, one solution would be to use conditional aggregation:

- recover all transactions where the customer's email appears in the `em_paid_to` or in the `em_paid_by` clause
- group by customer (a sensible option is to add the customer id to the `GROUP BY` clause, eventhough it is not part of the results)
- do conditional counts and sums, depending on whether the records was matched on `em_paid_to` or `em_paid_by`

The following query gives you detailed information (count of payments by and to, amounts paid by and to, and balance), you can pick what's relevant for you:

```
SELECT 
    c.f_name, 
    c.l_name, 
    SUM(c.email = t.em_paid_by) count_paid_by, 
    SUM(c.email = t.em_paid_to) count_paid_to, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.email = t.em_paid_by THEN t.amound ELSE 0 END) total_paid_by,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.email = t.em_paid_to THEN t.amound ELSE 0 END) total_paid_to,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.email = t.em_paid_by THEN t.amound ELSE -1 * t.amount END) balance
FROM 
    customer c 
    INNER JOIN transaction t
        ON c.email IN (t.em_paid_by, t.em_paid_to)
GROUP BY 
    c.cust_id, 
    c.f_name, 
    c.l_name
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would unpivot the data and aggregate:

```
select t.email, c.fname, c.lname, sum(t.amount)
from ((select em_paid_by as email, -amount as amount
       from transaction t
      ) union all
      (select em_paid_to, amount
       from transaction t
      )
     ) t
group by email;
```

You can join to the `customer` table to get the additional customer information:

```
select email, sum(amount)
from cusomer c join
     ((select em_paid_by as email, -amount as amount
       from transaction t
      ) union all
      (select em_paid_to, amount
       from transaction t
      )
     ) t
     on c.email = t.email
group by t.email, c.fname, c.lname;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause:

```
select c.*,
    coalesce((
        select sum(amount)
        from transaction t
        where t.em_paid_by = c.email
    ), 0)
    -
    coalesce((
        select sum(amount)
        from transaction t
        where t.em_paid_to = c.email
    ), 0) as paid_balance
from customer c
```

If you want more information like the count of transactions, I would use subqueries in the FROM clause:

```
select c.*,
    p.cnt_paid,
    r.cnt_received
    coalesce(p.sum_paid, 0) as sum_paid,
    coalesce(r.sum_received, 0) as sum_received,
    coalesce(p.sum_paid, 0) - coalesce(r.sum_received, 0) as paid_balance,
    p.cnt_paid + r.cnt_received as total_transactions
from customer c
left join (
    select em_paid_by as email, sum(amount) as sum_paid, count(*) as cnt_paid
    from transaction
    group by em_paid_by
) p on p.email = c.email
left join (
    select em_paid_to as email, sum(amount) as sum_received, count(*) as cnt_received
    from transaction
    group by em_paid_to
) r on r.email = c.email
```